# Date.after not working for me

Tags: java, android

I have a Date in String , "2016-6-26", that I want to compare with current date and if my date is equals or greater then current date i want do do some tasks.
i have implemented the following code but it always gives me valid whatever date i select.

```
String[] parts = date.split("-");  //where date is 2016-6-26
    String part1 = parts[0]; //2016
    String part2 = parts[1];  //6
    String part3 = parts[2];  //26
    String valid_until =part3+"/"+part2+"/"+part1; //"26/06/2016";        // "28/02/2016";
    Log.d("soh_valid", valid_until);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date strDate = null;
    try {
        strDate = sdf.parse(valid_until);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (new Date().after(strDate)) {
        Log.d("new_date", String.valueOf(new Date()));
     Toast.makeText(VASActivity.this,"valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(VASActivity.this,"Not valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

what i am doing wrong here?
any suggestion?

Comment: Does the parsing even work? Because the ``6`` from your original string does not magically turn into a ``06`` like you expect it to.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why don't you use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` rather than splitting and reformatting?

Comment: @f1sh i add 0 with month to but it was not working aswell

Comment: @KenY-N yes i was using new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); before but got same issue

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is:

> if my date is equals or greater then current date i want do do some tasks

Your code is:

```
if (new Date().after(strDate)) {
   // Do stuff since valid
}
```

However, the [documentation for `after`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) states:

```
public boolean after(Date when)
    Tests if this date is after the specified date.
Returns:
    true if and only if the instant represented by this Date object is
    strictly later than the instant represented by when; false otherwise.
```

So, it is true if the current date (got via `new Date`) is greater than your date, the exact opposite of your requirement. Therefore, you should [use `before`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)).

Comment: i used before it works fine for dates greater than current date.but its not working for current date.what about current date

Comment: You could either say `if (!new Date().after(strDate))` or `if (new Date().equals(strDate) || new Date().before(strDate))`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you need not to split by "-" and then append with "/"

```
String d="2016-6-26";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(d);
        Date currentDate=new Date();
        if(date1.equals(currentDate) || date1.after(currentDate))
        {
            //your logic here
        }
```

Comment: the month (``6``) does not work with this pattern (``MM``).

Comment: @f1sh My bad, Fixed. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @f1sh Incorrect: [it says here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) "For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields."

Comment: @SpringLearner not working for current date. is it working for you??

Comment: @SohailYasin what do you mean by not working? did you see the screenshot?

Comment: @SpringLearner yes i do. it is working fine for other dates.but at current date its not working .it goes to else condition

Comment: @SohailYasin If your d is the current date string then it wont work because d does not has time, but currentDate has time. So it will always goes to else condition except midnight where the time is 00:00:00

Comment: @SpringLearner i have make date check on php side